# Launch an action from setInterval when tab is hidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, timer

Chrome has announced that [its new version will throttle timers even more](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/). What is the recommended way in which I can guarantee that a specific action (API request) is called after X milliseconds if the tab is still active but hidden?

Comment: Link provided by you already contains recommendations and describe algorithms when and how timers would be throttled. Also in JavaScript even for visible page no guarantee that timer would be called exactly after N milliseconds

Comment: Hi @maksimr. Indeed, they do offer some solutions, but I don't see a clear one for my case. At the same time, I'm not looking for a very precise timer (+/- 1s is reasonable). An example of a use case: the user gets a form and 30 minutes to complete it, at the end of which I want to make an API call. Rather than tricking the browser into thinking the tab is active (heartbeats through WebSockets, low-frequency audio played in a loop, etc), I was wondering if there is a clear recommendation to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: And I guess an 'academic' curiosity as well, to see if it's actually possible.

Comment: For your use case, if my understand was not wrong, isn't it just an async wait function, with an end condition that whether the form is completed. Once the `wait` is resolved, make your API call.

Comment: HI @Wenbo. The example use would be that the user has 1h to complete a form. If he hasn't done it then we need to submit it ASAP automatically

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut, yes, the conditional `wait` function still can meet your requirement. If you think that sounds what you need, then I can write down the function as an answer.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut it seems like you're only setting one timer, right? If you aren't chaining your timers (using setInterval, or calling setTimeout inside a setTimeout), then the link you've sent states that they will be throttled such that they're checked once per second. The intensive throttling only happens after the chain length is 5 or more.

Comment: What kind of timer precision are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

The `wait` function I said is like

```
function wait(timeoutInMilliseconds, waitConditionFunc, interval=50) {
    const date = new Date();
    if (timeoutInMilliseconds > 0) {
        date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + timeoutInMilliseconds);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!waitConditionFunc || !waitConditionFunc()) {
            //if there is no condition, or after checking the condition, we don't need to wait, resolve
            resolve();
        }

        //check the condition intervally until the condition func indicates that we don't need to wait, or time out
        let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (!waitConditionFunc || !waitConditionFunc()) {
                //if there is no condition, or after checking the condition, we don't need to wait, resolve
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                resolve();
            }
            if (timeoutInMilliseconds > 0 && Date.now() >= date) {
                //time out
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                reject("timeout");
            }
        }, interval);
    });
}
```

You can call the `wait` by passing say 3600000 (1 hour, or passing `0` for no timeout), and the function of validating the form (or passing `null` for just waiting for 1 hour). Hope I didn't misunderstand your question and this function helps.